# Issue with Tensorflow Interpreter in IOS release build

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow, flutter-dependencies, tensorflow-lite

I am passing the tflite file to interpreter but it return nothing. This is only happening when i download the IOS build from test flight. Running app with IDE works fine.

```
tfl.Interpreter? interpreter = await tfl.Interpreter.fromAsset('assets/config/mobilefacenet.tflite');
```

i have also tried

```
tfl.Interpreter.fromFile(File(path));
```

But this also don't return anything.

**How i am testing:**
I have add a stack view with a Text widget on that and add logs into a string and print the text to check which line is executed. I am not getting any error even if i add this interpreter into try catch. I have add a text before assigning the value to the interpreter and after the value is assigned to the interpreter only the before added text shows not after one. This is why i am assuming it get stuck while assigning and didn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have follow to step from: https://github.com/tensorflow/flutter-tflite#android--ios

When creating a release archive (IPA), the symbols are stripped by Xcode, so the command flutter build ipa may throw a Failed to lookup symbol ... symbol not found error. To work around this:

In Xcode, go to Target Runner > Build Settings > Strip Style
Change from All Symbols to Non-Global Symbols

It's working fine on iPhone 8 above